# Objective C- Loading a UIPickerview using the objects in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

i have a picker view which contains values from an NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int t=-20 ;t<70;t++)
{
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",t];
[array addObject:string];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row{
return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

I select a value from the picker and save it in database. Afterwards when the page is loaded picker should be loaded with the saved value.

How can I achieve it?

I have seen accessing selected row by passing index value like

```
[pickerview selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

but in my case is it possible to get the values' index ?or is there any other way?

please help

Comment: Are you able to show data in picker view?

Comment: yes i am able to show the data

Comment: You can obtain an index this way: [array indexOfObject: @"your saved value from DB"]. But before selection that row check if index is not NSNotFound

Answer (score 0):

As you model will change so you can send indexOfObject message to array to get index. Try This

```
 NSInteger index=[array indexOfObject:@"ObjectYouHave"];
```

Comment: Tried this- NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[datafromdb objectForKey@"pickervalue"]integerValue]];                              NSInteger index=[array indexOfObject:num];       if(NSNotFound==index)    NSLog(@"not found");                                                                          else  [pickerview selectedRowInComponent:index];                                      But it always prints the nslog  ,and database has the value which is present in the picker.Where am I going wrong?